# How to check if a number of both synchronous and asynchronous javascript promises have completed

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, synchronous

I am new to using promises in javascript and I just cannot seem to get something that (I think) should be fairly basic working.

I am writing code for a turn-based game where during a player's turn, a number of things happen of which some are asynchronous (for example animations using `setInterval`), while some are vanilla synchronous code. What I am trying to do is to determine when ALL of the functions required during a player's turn have completed, so that I can switch turns to the next player. The client side is pure HTML5/CSS/JS (using the canvas API for animation), while the back-end is PHP 8.1 and MySQL5.6 in case it matters.

The relevant functions of my current code look like this:

```
function performAction() {
  // this is the function that is fired when the player presses a button to perform some action, for example "move 5 tiles"

  // a few hundred lines of code to do stuff client-side like move validation etc.

  drawPlayer(); // we now fire the client-side animation function so that players get instant feedback and don't need to wait for the server response in multi-player games

  // if this is a multi-player online game, we now call a function to fetch data from the server, for example to check if this player is blocked from taking that move
  if (gameType == "remoteHuman") {
    sendAction(data);
    }

  // otherwise, we don't need to contact the server if the player is playing a local AI game and can continue with the remaining actions
  else {
    completeAction(data);
  }
}

function completeAction(data) {
  // this function carries out the remaining tasks required on the client based on either the server response, or being called directly from performAction in local, single-player games

  updateStats(); // update all the player's stats
  textOverlay(); // draw a nice, floaty text overlay that shows some numbers and fades out
}

function updateStats() {
  // this function is maybe a hundred lines of standard, synchronous code that updates player statistics like health etc.

  // we are at the bottom of the code, so the updateStats function has now completed at this point since it's synchronous
}

function drawPlayer() {
  // this function is the main animation function and is called towards the end of function performAction so that the player gets nice, instant response to actions without waiting for server responses etc.

  function animate() {
    // this is the core animation function that performs the canvas API drawing for each frame of an animation

    // if we have finished drawing all the animation frames, then we are OK to clear the timer
    if (currentFrame == frames.length) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      // the drawPlayer function has now completed at this point
    }
  }

  // set up the locally scoped timer to run the animation function every frameDelay (about 20ms) for smooth animations
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    animate();
  }, frameDelay);
}

function textOverlay() {
  // this function is a canvas drawing function that draws nice floaty text that fades out

  // about a hundred lines of bog standard canvas api code here

  // the actual, asynch drawing code. we delay the text overlay by about 500ms to better synchronise with animation actions first
  setTimeout(function(){
    // then we draw something and slowly reduce the opacity every frameDelay (about 20ms) until the text fades out
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      // when our alpha is below zero, we know the text isn't on the screen anymore
      if (alpha < 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        // the textOverlay function has now completed at this point
      }         
    }, frameDelay);
  }, animationDelay);
}

function sendAction(data) {
  // this function is called from performAction whenever an event needs to be sent to the server in a multiplayer game. bog standard stuff. nothing to see here, move along
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

      completeAction(data);
    }

  xhttp.open("GET", serverURL + "?data=" + data);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

I should note that all the above code works perfectly. What I need to know is when the functions drawPlayer, textOverlay, and updateStats have ALL completed, without chaining them in promises since I want them to all run asynchronously. I am only interested in when ALL of the functions have completed. The functions can never fail, so there is no need for error catching or failed response checking. Some stats about the functions:

- drawPlayer: has an asynch component mainly based on setInterval. takes anywhere between 200-1000ms to complete on a typical client, depending on the player action taken
- textOverlay: has an asynch component mainly based on setInterval. takes anywhere between 100-500ms to complete on a typical client
- updateStats: purely synchronous code. takes maybe 2-5ms to complete on a typical client. however, it is essential that this function has completed before the turn passes to the other player, so I need it included in the promise "chain" even though it is synchronous with low execution time compared to the drawing/animation functions

This is what I have tried so far:

1. Instantiate a promise in performAction just before the call to drawPlayer(). Then at each point in the 3 dependent function when I know for sure that the functions have completed, I add a "then". Code below:

```
// set up as a global variable so that it can be accessed within any function in my code
var promiseA = new Promise(function(resolve) {
  resolve(value);
  console.log("promiseA created", value);
});

function performAction() {
  // this is the function that is fired when the player presses a button to perform some action, for example "move 5 tiles"

  // a few hundred lines of code to do stuff client-side like move validation etc.

  drawPlayer(); // we now fire the client-side animation function so that players get instant feedback and don't need to wait for the server response in multi-player games

  // if this is a multi-player online game, we now call a function to fetch data from the server, for example to check if this player is blocked from taking that move
  if (gameType == "remoteHuman") {
    sendAction(data);
    }

  // otherwise, we don't need to contact the server if the player is playing a local AI game and can continue with the remaining actions
  else {
    completeAction(data);
  }
}

function completeAction(data) {
  // this function carries out the remaining tasks required on the client based on either the server response, or being called directly from performAction in local, single-player games

  updateStats(); // update all the player's stats
  textOverlay(); // draw a nice, floaty text overlay that shows some numbers and fades out
}

function updateStats() {
  // this function is maybe a hundred lines of standard, synchronous code that updates player statistics like health etc.

  // we are at the bottom of the code, so the updateStats function has now completed at this point since it's synchronous
  gv.promiseA.then(
    function resolve(value) {
      console.log("this function has completed", Date.now() - value);
    }
  );
}

function drawPlayer() {
  // this function is the main animation function and is called towards the end of function performAction so that the player gets nice, instant response to actions without waiting for server responses etc.

  function animate() {
    // this is the core animation function that performs the canvas API drawing for each frame of an animation

    // if we have finished drawing all the animation frames, then we are OK to clear the timer
    if (currentFrame == frames.length) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      // the drawPlayer function has now completed at this point
      gv.promiseA.then(
        function resolve(value) {
          console.log("this function has completed", Date.now() - value);
        }
      );
    }
  }

  // set up the locally scoped timer to run the animation function every frameDelay (about 20ms) for smooth animations
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    animate();
  }, frameDelay);
}

function textOverlay() {
  // this function is a canvas drawing function that draws nice floaty text that fades out

  // about a hundred lines of bog standard canvas api code here

  // the actual, asynch drawing code. we delay the text overlay by about 500ms to better synchronise with animation actions first
  setTimeout(function(){
    // then we draw something and slowly reduce the opacity every frameDelay (about 20ms) until the text fades out
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      // when our alpha is below zero, we know the text isn't on the screen anymore
      if (alpha < 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        // the textOverlay function has now completed at this point
        gv.promiseA.then(
          function resolve(value) {
            console.log("this function has completed", Date.now() - value);
          }
        );
      }         
    }, frameDelay);
  }, animationDelay);
}

function sendAction(data) {
  // this function is called from performAction whenever an event needs to be sent to the server in a multiplayer game. bog standard stuff. nothing to see here, move along
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

      completeAction(data);
    }

  xhttp.open("GET", serverURL + "?data=" + data);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

However, this doesn't work because it just tells me when each "then" has completed, and not necessarily when all the "thens" have completed because I don't think this is proper chaining. But also, I don't want the functions to be truly "chained" since they need to all to start and run asynchronously as none of the functions are dependent on the results of the other functions, and anyway making them run in series would just slow things down for no reason.

2. I've also tried instantiating 3 different promises (promiseA, promiseB, promiseC) at each point in the dependent code when I know the asynch functions will have completed. I then use an "all settled" check at the end of function completeAction():

```
// set up three global variables so that they can be accessed within any function in my code
var promiseA, promiseB, promiseC;

function performAction() {
  // this is the function that is fired when the player presses a button to perform some action, for example "move 5 tiles"

  // a few hundred lines of code to do stuff client-side like move validation etc.

  drawPlayer(); // we now fire the client-side animation function so that players get instant feedback and don't need to wait for the server response in multi-player games

  // if this is a multi-player online game, we now call a function to fetch data from the server, for example to check if this player is blocked from taking that move
  if (gameType == "remoteHuman") {
    sendAction(data);
    }

  // otherwise, we don't need to contact the server if the player is playing a local AI game and can continue with the remaining actions
  else {
    completeAction(data);
  }
}

function completeAction(data) {
  // this function carries out the remaining tasks required on the client based on either the server response, or being called directly from performAction in local, single-player games

  updateStats(); // update all the player's stats
  textOverlay(); // draw a nice, floaty text overlay that shows some numbers and fades out

  // check if all three promises have been resolved before running a function to hand over play to the next player
  Promise.allSettled([promiseA, promiseB, promiseC]).then(([result]) => {
    var value = Date.now();
    console.log("all functions completed", value);
    console.log(result);
    console.log("play can now be handed over to the other play");
    nextPlayerTurn();
  });
}

function updateStats() {
  // this function is maybe a hundred lines of standard, synchronous code that updates player statistics like health etc.

  // we are at the bottom of the code, so the updateStats function has now completed at this point since it's synchronous
  promiseA = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var value = Date.now();
    resolve(value);
    console.log("this function has completed", value);
  });
}

function drawPlayer() {
  // this function is the main animation function and is called towards the end of function performAction so that the player gets nice, instant response to actions without waiting for server responses etc.

  function animate() {
    // this is the core animation function that performs the canvas API drawing for each frame of an animation

    // if we have finished drawing all the animation frames, then we are OK to clear the timer
    if (currentFrame == frames.length) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      // the drawPlayer function has now completed at this point
      promiseB = new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var value = Date.now();
        resolve(value);
        console.log("this function has completed", value);
      });
    }
  }

  // set up the locally scoped timer to run the animation function every frameDelay (about 20ms) for smooth animations
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    animate();
  }, frameDelay);
}

function textOverlay() {
  // this function is a canvas drawing function that draws nice floaty text that fades out

  // about a hundred lines of bog standard canvas api code here

  // the actual, asynch drawing code. we delay the text overlay by about 500ms to better synchronise with animation actions first
  setTimeout(function(){
    // then we draw something and slowly reduce the opacity every frameDelay (about 20ms) until the text fades out
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      // when our alpha is below zero, we know the text isn't on the screen anymore
      if (alpha < 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        // the textOverlay function has now completed at this point
        promiseC = new Promise(function(resolve) {
          var value = Date.now();
          resolve(value);
          console.log("this function has completed", value);
        });
      }         
    }, frameDelay);
  }, animationDelay);
}

function sendAction(data) {
  // this function is called from performAction whenever an event needs to be sent to the server in a multiplayer game. bog standard stuff. nothing to see here, move along
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

      completeAction(data);
    }

  xhttp.open("GET", serverURL + "?data=" + data);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

However this also doesn't work and produces similar results to #1 above.

I know I am missing something fundamental here in my first use of promises, but I am also sure based on reading all the MDN documentation (but perhaps not fully understanding it or misinterpreting it) that promises should be able to work for this use case.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "synchronous and asynchronous promises" ... aren't promises asynchronous by nature

Comment: @Bravo From my reading of MDN, I think so yes. But for my use case I want to include the completion of a synchronous function in the "then" chain because it MUST complete before I can run the next function which should be triggered after both the synchronous and asynchronous functions have completed.

Comment: @Bravo Maybe My terms are wrong, but I guess I didn't mean "synchronous" promise, but rather "including a synchronous function within the asynchronous promise chain" if that makes more sense.

Comment: No, it doesn't any sense, since most functions are synchronous in JS. you can use non promises in Promise.all if that's what you are asking - it's not clear from the documentation for Promise.all, but it's definitely stated that not all values in the passed in iterable have to be promises (in fact, you can use Promise.all on exclusively non-promise values and it still works)

Comment: @Bravo OK, maybe post an answer using Promise.all?

Comment: `Promisel.all([1,2,3]).then(console.log)` - or read the documentation on MDN

Comment: Show *where* and *how* you're creating the promises in the function you're waiting for. I'm pretty sure the issue is that you're not actually putting the code you're waiting for inside your promises, so they're just resolving immediately.

Comment: @Dradonfang Yes, I think you're right - I may be resolving the promises immediately, but I don't know how to "defer resolution"? But I'll update  my question so that people can see where in the code I've added my "thens".

Comment: `I may be resolving the promises immediately` ... where? you can't determine when a Promise resolves if it's a network request (I see you have one of those, except it does eff all with Promises)

Comment: @Arj not where you put your "thens", where you create your promises. Specifically, we need to see the functions you're passing to the Promise constructor. Your async code needs to be *inside* that function, or otherwise able to call its resolve method.

Comment: @Dragonfang I've updated my 2 example codes as you've suggested (I didn't do it when I first posted the question because I thought it would make it a huge amount of text).

Comment: @Arj yeah that's very wrong lol, give me a few minutes to type up an answer.

Comment: @ Drangonfang Thanks so much. I really want to understand Promises and avoid callback hell, but they're just not making any sense to me :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using promises correctly. (That's understandable, they're confusing). Specifically, you're:

1. creating empty Promises
2. misusing `then()`.

### Creating empty Promises

Currently, your promise is being created and resolved immediately.

When you create a promise, you pass it a function with a parameter (which is itself a function) named `resolve`. The promise get completed *when you call that resolve parameter*. That Your asynchronous code needs to go *inside* this function, because you need to call `resolve()` it only *after* your async code is done - or you can use a hack to get this function and call it elsewhere.

### then()

When you call `.then`, you're simply adding another function or promise that uses the return value of the previous promise in the chain, after that promise resolves. Since your promise has already resolved, the `then()` executes and returns immediately, not doing you any good.

### So how do you fix it?

Your code is a little difficult to stuff inside a promise, so you can use a little trick to [resolve promises externally](https://lea.verou.me/2016/12/resolve-promises-externally-with-this-one-weird-trick/) and combine it with async/await.

Let's look at implementing this for `sendAction`:

```js
// Change function to async; This means it returns a promise, 
//  and you can use async...await
async function sendAction(data) {
    var resolver = {} // An object to smuggle resolve() out of scope
    var done = new Promise(function(resolve) {
        resolver.resolve = resolve // This is the function that resolves the promise
    })
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // note that our callback function is "async" now
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = async function () { 
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            await completeAction(data); // this will be async too
            // Only now that all the asynchronous code is complete...
            resolver.resolve() // ...do we resolve the promise
        }
    }

    xhttp.open("GET", serverURL + "?data=" + data);
    xhttp.send();
    // The function will wait until the "done" promise is resolved
    await done;
}
```

The `async` and `await` help write somewhat more readable and understandable code without having to muck about too much with promises, and and async functions return promises themselves.

Implemented for the rest of the code, using async/await:

```
async function performAction() {
    // this is the function that is fired when the player presses a button to perform some action, for example "move 5 tiles"

    // a few hundred lines of code to do stuff client-side like move validation etc.

    var playerDrawn = drawPlayer(); // we now fire the client-side animation function so that players get instant feedback and don't need to wait for the server response in multi-player games

    // if this is a multi-player online game, we now call a function to fetch data from the server, for example to check if this player is blocked from taking that move
    if (gameType == "remoteHuman") {
        await sendAction(data);
    }

    // otherwise, we don't need to contact the server if the player is playing a local AI game and can continue with the remaining actions
    else {
        await completeAction(data);
    }

    await playerDrawn
}

async function completeAction(data) {
    // this function carries out the remaining tasks required on the client based on either the server response, or being called directly from performAction in local, single-player games

    updateStats(); // update all the player's stats
    await textOverlay(); // draw a nice, floaty text overlay that shows some numbers and fades out
}


function updateStats() {
    // this function is maybe a hundred lines of standard, synchronous code that updates player statistics like health etc.

    // we are at the bottom of the code, so the updateStats function has now completed at this point since it's synchronous
}

async function drawPlayer() {
    // this function is the main animation function and is called towards the end of function performAction so that the player gets nice, instant response to actions without waiting for server responses etc.

    var resolver = {}
    var done = new Promise(function(resolve) {
        resolver.resolve = resolve
    })
    function animate() {
        // this is the core animation function that performs the canvas API drawing for each frame of an animation

        // if we have finished drawing all the animation frames, then we are OK to clear the timer
        if (currentFrame == frames.length) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            // the drawPlayer function has now completed at this point
            resolver.resolve()
        }
    }

    // set up the locally scoped timer to run the animation function every frameDelay (about 20ms) for smooth animations
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        animate();
    }, frameDelay);

    await done;
}

async function textOverlay() {
    // this function is a canvas drawing function that draws nice floaty text that fades out

    // about a hundred lines of bog standard canvas api code here

    var resolver = {}
    var done = new Promise(function(resolve) {
        resolver.resolve = resolve
    })
    // the actual, asynch drawing code. we delay the text overlay by about 500ms to better synchronise with animation actions first
    setTimeout(function () {
        // then we draw something and slowly reduce the opacity every frameDelay (about 20ms) until the text fades out
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            // when our alpha is below zero, we know the text isn't on the screen anymore
            if (alpha < 0) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                // the textOverlay function has now completed at this point
                resolver.resolve()
            }
        }, frameDelay);
    }, animationDelay);

    await done;
}

async function sendAction(data) {
    // this function is called from performAction whenever an event needs to be sent to the server in a multiplayer game. bog standard stuff. nothing to see here, move along
    var resolver = {}
    var done = new Promise(function(resolve) {
        resolver.resolve = resolve
    })
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = async function () {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

            await completeAction(data);
            resolver.resolve()
        }
    }

    xhttp.open("GET", serverURL + "?data=" + data);
    xhttp.send();
    await done;
}
```

Now that you've put all your logic inside `performAction()`, you can use the promise it returns like so:

```
performAction().then(() => {
    var value = Date.now();
    console.log("all functions completed", value);
    console.log("play can now be handed over to the other play");
    nextPlayerTurn();
});
```

There's lots of optimizations you can make there to help make the code more elegant, but I tried to change it as little as possible and work with what you had.

The biggest suggestion I'd make is replace all of the `XMLHttpRequest` stuff in `sendAction()` with the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), which natively uses promises and is much more modern and easy to work with.

edit: Other suggested reading:

- [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Comment: I think that works! And your code example is much easier to follow than the MDN articles I'm trying to read. I'm going to run a series of tests to see if it works in all cases, but thank you, I think I'm on the right track now :)

Comment: Yeah I don't know why the MDN articles are so bad at explaining how promises actually work tbh. I didn't really *get* promises until I saw blog posts like the one I linked to deconstructing them for the purpose of circumventing them.

Remember to accept my answer once you've tested your code and it works :) Hopefully I've avoided any typos there.

Comment: will do; just saw your further updates and am working on those as well. I'll accept your answer when I'm done :)